# "Signing for "Parse-Parse" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor."

Tags: ios, cocoapods, parse-ios-sdk

I have a simple Xcode project that uses both Cocoapods and SPM to handle dependencies, Cocoapods being used only for Parse iOS SDK.

I don't exactly know when this started, but everytime I run `pod install` or `pod update` now, a `Parse-Parse` target gets added to the Pods project and prevents me from compiling - I need to manually remove it everytime.

[image]

If I don't remove it, I get this error when building the project:

> Pods.xcodeproj error project: Signing for "Parse-Parse" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

Any idea of what happened and what to do?

Thank you for your help